# I can't find out transaction history in sandbox use paypal checkout-sdk

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I use java `checkout-sdk-1.0.4` to develop PayPal payment. I successfully submit an order to PayPal, get the payment url.

I log in with personal account and click the `continue` button.

[image]

And then paypal just redirect to the url i set.

```
http://localhost:38001/checkout/submit/result?token=60X99286YV4394812&PayerID=9WXE2YPSNEJSN
```

I can see the api call history in developer dashboard.
[image]

But i can't see any transaction history in my business account and personal account.
[image]

How do I determine if my payment is successful。

---

I try this tutorial from here

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/create-order/

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/capture-order/

At the end, paypal return capture success.

```
Status Code: 201
Status: COMPLETED
Order ID: 1AL061567P026410J
Links: 
    self: https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/1AL061567P026410J
Capture ids:
    6NY33838LX3268618
```

But i still can't see transaction history in my personal test account.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But I can't see any transaction history in my business account and personal account. enter image description here

You can't see any transaction because there is no transaction. There won't be any, unless you show the required order review page and perform the required capture API call when the customer returns to your site. (if you want to skip showing a review page and proceed directly with making the API call, then you should set the application_context object's user_action to 'PAY_NOW', so the last button's text is changed from 'Continue' to 'Pay Now' and the user knows to expect no review page. You still need to perform the API call to capture regardless).

---

The flow you are using of redirecting over to PayPal and then showing a review page or doing a capture call after being redirected back, is an old checkout flow and does not provide the best user experience. It is better to *not use any redirects*. At all.

Instead, make two routes on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls). These routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). The latter one should (on success) store the payment details in your database before it does the return (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, the PayPal transaction ID)

Pair those two routes with the following approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: Is a complete transaction should do `create order` and `capture order`?

Comment: Capturing an order successfully will result in a transaction.  The transaction ID is returned in `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`.  If you don't receive that value, you don't have a transaction.

Comment: I have update my question, i capture the order and get capture id, but still can't see transaction.

Comment: It's a completed transaction, so it will be there. Make sure you are logging into https://www.sandbox.paypal.com with the correct sandbox Business account from https://www.paypal.com/signin?returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Faccounts%2F

Comment: Remember, you must log into the one associated with the REST app of your sandbox client-id: https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications

Comment: : (   I am very sure the login url and personal account is correct. I have only one test personal account and one test business account, i pay and logging into sandbox.paypal.com with the same personal account. That's strange。

Comment: You should log in with the Business account to verify the payment. The Personal account is only for making the payment and is not important after.

Comment: There is no transaction history in the business account.

Comment: I can get transaction info with `Get Transaction Api`, but nothing in business account `Activity` page.

Comment: That's a reporting delay then, the transaction is too recent to show in the sandbox activity/history. But it's completed, there's nothing more you need to worry about from an integration standpoint.